# How to parse the Json response in android?

Tags: android, json, parsing

i m getting this response in a result of GET request to server

```
{"LL": { "control": "dev/sys/getkey", "value": "4545453030304138303046392035343733373432363020323031332D30322D31312031383A30313A3135", "Code": "200"}}
```

i just want to extract the value of `"value"` from the above json response.

I m using this code to get this response

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(
                        "http://192.168.14.247/jdev/sys/getkey"));
                response = client.execute(request);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String responseText = null;
            try {
                responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Parse Exception", e + "");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("IO Exception 2", e + "");

            }

            Log.i("responseText", responseText);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, responseText + "",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

my question is that how can i parse this and get the value of only `"value"` tag.
thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can parse current json String to get `value` from it as :

```
// Convert String to json object
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseText);

// get LL json object
JSONObject json_LL = json.getJSONObject("LL");

// get value from LL Json Object
String str_value=json_LL.getString("value"); //<< get value here
```

Comment: @QadirHussain : mean im not getting u. yes u are getting json string from server

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(responseText);   
String value = json.getJSONObject("LL").getString("value");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
JSONObject json= json1.getJSONObject("LL");    

String value= json.getString("value");
```

Comment: im not able to find any Json Array in current json String as provided with question ?

Comment: LL is not jsonArray, it's jsonObject

Comment: how is it different to @ρяσѕρєяK answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
JSONObject ResponseObject = new JSONObject(Response);
String str = ResponseObject.getJSONObject("LL").getString(value);
```

Comment: Thanks for help.. I want ask one this more. is this Json Response i m getting? and parsing

Comment: how is it different to @ρяσѕρєяK answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your response and get value try this:

```
try {
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);// Convert response string in to json object.

  JSONObject jsonLL = jsonObject.getJSONObject("LL");// Get LL json object from jsonObject.

  String strValue = jsonLL.getString("value");// Get value from jsonLL Object.

   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simple and Efficient** solution :  Use Googlle's **Gson library**

- Put this in **build.gradle** file :    `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'`
- Now convert the JSON String to a convenient datastrucutre like HashMap in **2 lines** like this.

---

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson(JsonString , type);
```

---

### or you can use this below class :

To convert your **JSON string to hashmap** use this :

```
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>(Utility.jsonToMap(response)) ;
```

**Use this class :)** (handles even lists , nested lists and json)

```
public class Utility {

    public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(Object json) throws JSONException {

        if(json instanceof JSONObject)
            return _jsonToMap_((JSONObject)json) ;

        else if (json instanceof String)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject((String)json) ;
            return _jsonToMap_(jsonObject) ;
        }
        return null ;
    }


   private static Map<String, Object> _jsonToMap_(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(json != JSONObject.NULL) {
            retMap = toMap(json);
        }
        return retMap;
    }


    private static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
        while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysItr.next();
            Object value = object.get(key);

            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }


    public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Object value = array.get(i);
            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            list.add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

---

Thank me later :)