# HttpURLConnection with AsyncTask too slow (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

i try to get datas from internet and save them in variables, but the process is too slow... here my code:

```
`public class CurrConvert extends AsyncTask {

    boolean connection = true;

    float exchangeRate(final String currencyFrom, final String currencyTo) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + currencyFrom + currencyTo + "=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        String result = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
        return Float.parseFloat(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage(getContext().getString(R.string.updating));
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        try {
            USD_AUD = exchangeRate("USD", "AUD");
            USD_CAD = exchangeRate("USD", "CAD");
            USD_EUR = exchangeRate("USD", "EUR");
            USD_GBP = exchangeRate("USD", "GBP");
            USD_INR = exchangeRate("USD", "INR");
            USD_JPY = exchangeRate("USD", "JPY");
            USD_SGD = exchangeRate("USD", "SGD");

            EUR_AUD = exchangeRate("EUR", "AUD");
            EUR_CAD = exchangeRate("EUR", "CAD");
            EUR_GBP = exchangeRate("EUR", "GBP");
            EUR_INR = exchangeRate("EUR", "INR");
            EUR_JPY = exchangeRate("EUR", "JPY");
            EUR_SGD = exchangeRate("EUR", "SGD");
            EUR_USD = exchangeRate("EUR", "USD");

            AUD_CAD = exchangeRate("AUD", "CAD");
            AUD_EUR = exchangeRate("AUD", "EUR");
            AUD_GBP = exchangeRate("AUD", "GBP");
            AUD_INR = exchangeRate("AUD", "INR");
            AUD_JPY = exchangeRate("AUD", "JPY");
            AUD_SGD = exchangeRate("AUD", "SGD");
            AUD_USD = exchangeRate("AUD", "USD");

            CAD_AUD = exchangeRate("CAD", "AUD");
            CAD_EUR = exchangeRate("CAD", "EUR");
            CAD_GBP = exchangeRate("CAD", "GBP");
            CAD_INR = exchangeRate("CAD", "INR");
            CAD_JPY = exchangeRate("CAD", "JPY");
            CAD_SGD = exchangeRate("CAD", "SGD");
            CAD_USD = exchangeRate("CAD", "USD");

            SGD_AUD = exchangeRate("SGD", "AUD");
            SGD_CAD = exchangeRate("SGD", "CAD");
            SGD_EUR = exchangeRate("SGD", "EUR");
            SGD_GBP = exchangeRate("SGD", "GBP");
            SGD_INR = exchangeRate("SGD", "INR");
            SGD_JPY = exchangeRate("SGD", "JPY");
            SGD_USD = exchangeRate("SGD", "USD");

            GBP_AUD = exchangeRate("GBP", "AUD");
            GBP_CAD = exchangeRate("GBP", "CAD");
            GBP_EUR = exchangeRate("GBP", "EUR");
            GBP_INR = exchangeRate("GBP", "INR");
            GBP_JPY = exchangeRate("GBP", "JPY");
            GBP_SGD = exchangeRate("GBP", "SGD");
            GBP_USD = exchangeRate("GBP", "USD");

            JPY_AUD = exchangeRate("JPY", "AUD");
            JPY_CAD = exchangeRate("JPY", "CAD");
            JPY_EUR = exchangeRate("JPY", "EUR");
            JPY_GBP = exchangeRate("JPY", "GBP");
            JPY_INR = exchangeRate("JPY", "INR");
            JPY_SGD = exchangeRate("JPY", "SGD");
            JPY_USD = exchangeRate("JPY", "USD");

            INR_AUD = exchangeRate("INR", "AUD");
            INR_CAD = exchangeRate("INR", "CAD");
            INR_EUR = exchangeRate("INR", "EUR");
            INR_GBP = exchangeRate("INR", "GBP");
            INR_JPY = exchangeRate("INR", "JPY");
            INR_SGD = exchangeRate("INR", "SGD");
            INR_USD = exchangeRate("INR", "USD");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            connection = false;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (connection) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.no_connection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}`
```

doInBackground method takes almost 30 sec to complete the process... is there a way to be istantaneous?

Comment: Well, you are downloading a CSV, and storing each of the 56 requests in memory... Why do you expect that to be fast?

Comment: You could speed it up, for example, by not requesting the inverted conversion. If you know USD to EUR, then you don't need to lookup EUR to USD. Matter of fact, if you know one currency to all the others, then you should be able to just apply some math to do the conversion on the rest.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the suggestion! in this way I have a total of 7 requests so I could speed up my code

Comment: I'd probably go for the below answer for all currencies in JSON format. That would be one request. Making multiple requests when not necessary is not recommended as it drains the battery quicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call the `exchangeRate` method, a csv file has to be downloaded to extract the exchange rate value. You have a total of 56 requests, that's why your AsyncTask is too slow.

What I suggest is to use this link : [all currencies in JSON format](http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json).

Now, it's simple! Just decode the JSON response and you can refer to this link : [How to parse the Json response in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812560/how-to-parse-the-json-response-in-android).

Get the `responses` JSON Array, each JSON Object has the following structure (example) :

```
{
"resource" : { 
"classname" : "Quote",
"fields" : { 
"change" : "-0.006400",
"chg_percent" : "-0.481094",
"name" : "USD/AUD",
"price" : "1.323900",
"symbol" : "AUD=X",
"ts" : "1472750677",
"type" : "currency",
"utctime" : "2016-09-01T17:24:37+0000",
"volume" : "0"
}
}
}
```

All you have to do now is to get the `price`value which is in your case the exchange rate.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Is the frist time that i face JSON format, I try to follow your instruction, I hope this will solve my problem :) 
ps: the exchange rates of the link you suggest me, are live?

Comment: Yes, the values you get from the link are the latest! It's easy to deal with json, at least you learn something new with this solution ;)

Comment: Yeah! I have successfully implemented JSON ,  thanks for solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask runs by default at a lower priority to help making sure the UI thread will remain responsive, but you can change it:

```
protected Void doInBackground() {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    // do your work
}
```

Comment: Doesn't works for me (same time to complete the code)