# Android: Get JSON response

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to develop an app to call Flickr API method search to get the JSON response and everytime I do it, it returns an object reference like 'com.rdev.imagegallery.obj.FlickrPhotos@bb2935b' instead of JSON response.
I'm using MVVM and to read the

```
public ApiResponse(Response<T> response) {

    code = response.code();
    Timber.d("====Api Response");

    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
        Timber.d("response is success");
        body = response.body();
        Timber.d("Body:"+body.toString());<---------- response: com.rdev.imagegallery.obj.FlickrPhotos@bb2935b
        errorMessage = null;
    }
(...)
```

I'm using retrofit to call the Flickr API, passing the URL

```
return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.MAINBASEURL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(new LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

//call API Flickr
@Override
public LiveData<ApiResponse<FlickrPhotos>> getValues(String url) {
    Timber.d("URL:"+url);
    return mMainApiHelper.getValues(url);
}
```

The URL is correct (I'v already tested it). I have the interface to call the API.

public interface MainApiHelper {

```
@GET
LiveData<ApiResponse<FlickrPhotos>> getValues(@Url String url);
```

}

And I have a class FlickPhotos to "get" the result(everytime I made a call of API I get one object of this type):

```
public class FlickrPhotos {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private int page;

    @SerializedName("pages")
    @Expose
    private String pages;

    @SerializedName("perpage")
    @Expose
    private int perpage;

(...)
```

I've tried to verify which values I get after the call and they are all null (so I think the problem is on the call)

```
Timber.d("Answer:"+apiResponse.body.getPages());--->null
Timber.d("Answer:"+apiResponse.body.getPage());--->0
Timber.d("Answer:"+apiResponse.body.getStart());--->null
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but... if you don't show us the relevant code, how can we even begin? What you're showing here is akin to saying: I made a cake, it looks bad, what did I do wrong?.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini please tell me what code do you want I show you? I'm getting an object reference instead a "normal" response. Please help

Comment: You might consider expanding your [mcve] to show how you are actually making this Web service call and how you are using `ApiResponse`. For example, if you are using Retrofit, then what you are getting is exactly what you told Retrofit to do: call the Web service and turn the response into an instance of your `com.rdev.imagegallery.obj.FlickrPhotos` class.

Comment: What @CommonsWare said.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added more information.

Comment: Apparently, the JSON being returned by the URL does not match that Java object. You might consider using [an existing Flickr library](https://github.com/boncey/Flickr4Java).

Comment: I suggest trying to retrieve the json string response and then converting that to a POJO (there are tools online). Then compare the generated POJO with your FlickrPhotos.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't understand why I have to use it. I've already try to use a JSONObject and get the values and they are all null.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini any suggestion please?

Comment: @porthfind I think your model doesn't match what Flickr is returning, do what CommonsWare told you, compare the JSON that the API returns, and ensure it matches what you're asking your Json adapter to process... if the format doesn't match, you will get either nulls or exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my POJO class was wrongly defined.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58146179/11939647

you call the API and read the response and put it in Json objects.